# CSS problem with a html menu

Tags: html, css

i made a vertical menu. **I want that the first tab has a different color than the other ones.** I put the color black for the other one. Here's my code

in my html code i got the ul (class = "vertical") and in a "li" there's a link `<a>` .. the first one i put a id = "title"

CSS

```
.vertical{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%; 
}
#titre{
background: ##1C1C1C url(image/menu_PC/effet_fondu.gif) no-repeat right top;
}

.vertical li{
border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* white border beneath each menu item */
}


.vertical li a{
background: #6E6E6E url(image/menu_PC/effet_fondu.gif) no-repeat right top; 
font: bold 13px "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;
display: block;
color: white;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 0; /* Vertical (top/bottom) padding for each menu link */
text-indent: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

.vertical li a:visited, .vertical li a:active{
color: white;
}

.vertical li a:hover{
background-color: black; /*color of menu onMouseover*/
color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: **1.** You have `##1C1C1C` - fix the double hash. **2.** Could you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: I can but the tag make my code disappear

Comment: You need to indent each line with four spaces. You can do this by selecting the HTML and clicking the `{}` button. Or, if you simply can't get it to work, just paste it in anyway and I'll fix it.

Comment: @thirtydot: ok everything is fine.. i got your #1 mistake. (a novice mistake :P) Thanks there

Comment: You mean fixing that double hash fixed your entire problem? Wow, I really need to start posting these guess-comments as answers..

Comment: @thirtydot, Post it now, and reap the rewards! Also for posterity in case someone has the same problem and doesn't read the comments. @thorboy, please accept after thirtydot posts

Comment: @JOHNP: how can i accept if he doesn't post an answer?

Comment: @thorboy yes you have to wait till/if he posts :)

Comment: @ThorBoy, @JohnP: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I said in the comments:

> You have `##1C1C1C` - fix the double
>   hash.

Inside here:

```
#titre{
    background: ##1C1C1C url(image/menu_PC/effet_fondu.gif) no-repeat right top;
}
```

The entire `background` rule was being ignored due to the invalid colour format.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have id called "titre" in HTML, because you have called "titre" ID in CSS, and make sure you have following code too in css.

```
#titre
{  background: #1C1C1C url(image/menu_PC/effet_fondu.gif) no-repeat right top;}
```

I presume, you want to change name as "title", so you need to change in CSS code instead of titre.

Comment: I assume the `id` *is* actually `titre`. The questioner must be using French, see `titre` and `effet_fondu`.

Comment: Ya, i see, but he said that first one he put id is "title". I guess he like to change to match at HTML and CSS.